# Getting frequencies and magnitudes from audio sample using FFT

Tags: java, audio, fft, sampling, frequency-analysis

I am currently working on a music visualization LED strip display (similar to [this](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/interactive-led-music-visualizer/all)) but got stuck at the process of extracting audio frequency / magnitude from the sample data.

The entire process takes up quite a few steps, and I am not sure at which point I am failing exactly, so please bear with me. I start with reading audio from a `TargetDataLine` configured with [AudioFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat.html#AudioFormat(float,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean)).

```java
AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(new AudioFormat(8000.0f, 16, 1, true, true));
```

Next, I read the data as described in [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20090221151851/http://codeidol.com/java/swing/Audio/Build-an-Audio-Waveform-Display/). Only difference is that I am using a smaller buffer, effectively reading 64 bytes at a time.

Here is an example data read in this way from a [500Hz test tone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlEfshsoyZk).

```java
final byte[] buffer = { // 32 16-bit samples
        30, 111, 43, -19, 50, -74, 49, -54,
        41, 70, 26, 121, 7, -90, -13, -89,
        -31, -118, -44, 17, -51, 75, -50, 60,
        -42, -62, -27, -115, -8, 91, 12, 85,
        30, 106, 43, -34, 50, -93, 49, -76,
        41, 52, 26, 108, 7, -93, -13, -84,
        -31, -104, -44, 38, -51, 98, -50, 84,
        -42, -42, -27, -98, -8, 99, 12, 83
};
```

Next, I transform the sampled bytes into an array of `double` values in range [-1, 1]. I took inspiration from the aforementioned tutorial and [this code](https://www.javatips.net/api/etyllica-master/src/main/java/sound/capture/AudioHandler.java).

```java
final double[] samples = new double[buffer.length];
int sampleIndex = 0;
int byteIndex = 0;
while (byteIndex < buffer.length) {
    int low = buffer[byteIndex];
    ++byteIndex;
    int high = buffer[byteIndex];
    ++byteIndex;

    int sampleIntValue = ((high << 8) + (low & 0x00ff));
    double maxSampleValue = 32768;
    samples[2 * sampleIndex] = ((double) sampleIntValue) / maxSampleValue; // Transforming to [-1, 1]
    samples[(2 * sampleIndex) + 1] = 0; // Imaginary part
    ++sampleIndex;
}
```

Next, I perform a Fast Fourier Transform on the data using the [edu.emory.mathcs:JTransforms:2.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.emory.mathcs/JTransforms/2.4) library.

```java
final DoubleFFT_1D fft = new DoubleFFT_1D(samples.length / 2);
fft.complexForward(samples);
```

Then, I calculate frequencies and magnitudes as described in [this code](https://gist.github.com/pbattin/75fc5aa933543f56ce63b98ce0a7bc8b#file-gistfile1-java-L34-L54).

```java
final float sampleRate = 8000f;
final Map<Double, Double> frequenciesToMagnitudes = IntStream.range(0, samples.length / 2)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                index -> 2 * ((double) index / (double) samples.length) * sampleRate,
                index -> Math.log10(
                        Math.sqrt(
                                Math.pow(samples[2 * index], 2) // real part
                                        + Math.pow(samples[(2 * index) + 1], 2) // imaginary part
                        )
                )
        ));
```

I find the maximum magnitude so I can scale the displayed values accordingly.

```java
final double maximumMagnitude = frequenciesToMagnitudes.values().stream().max(Double::compare).orElse(0d);
```

And finally, I display the results (taller block represents a brighter LED).

```java
final char[] magnitudeDisplay = {'▁', '▂', '▃', '▄', '▅', '▆', '▇', '█'};
frequenciesToMagnitudes.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).forEach(frequencyToMagnitude -> {
    final double magnitudePercentage = frequencyToMagnitude.getValue() / maximumMagnitude;
    final int characterToDisplayIndex = Math.min(magnitudeDisplay.length - 1, Math.max(0, (int) (magnitudePercentage * magnitudeDisplay.length)));
    final char characterToDisplay = magnitudeDisplay[characterToDisplayIndex];
    System.out.print(characterToDisplay);
});
System.out.println();
```

From all this, I would expect to see two distinct spikes (my frequency + [alias region](https://youtu.be/dCeHOf4cJE0?t=150)), but instead there is 8.

```
▁▁▅▁▁▁█▁▁▁▄▁▁▁▅▁▁▁▅▁▁▁▄▁▁▁█▁▁▁▅▁
```

The number of spikes changes depending on frequency of audio playback (sometimes it's two, sometimes it's four), and the lower the frequency the more spikes I see.

My question is: how do I extract frequency / magnitude pairs from audio data?

Comment: Tried also with `com.github.wendykierp:JTransforms:3.1`, same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging I have found the [OpenIMAJ](https://github.com/openimaj/openimaj) library which does exactly what I need. Here are the differences in my code and their code.

1. Transforming from bytes to floating point is incorrect. All examples use big endian audio format, but take the bytes in the wrong order. It should be:

```java
int high = buffer[byteIndex];
++byteIndex;
int low = buffer[byteIndex];
++byteIndex;
```

2. [Size of FFT output is padded to next power of 2.](https://github.com/openimaj/openimaj/blob/545969f7a99c13bb5bd02c0a30f55013e4abca72/audio/audio-processing/src/main/java/org/openimaj/audio/analysis/FourierTransform.java#L112-L114) This was not a problem since I always chose a buffer of size that was a power of 2, but in case if your buffer is not, this will be necessary.

```java
final int fftSize = (int) Math.pow(2, 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(numberOfSamples - 1));
```

3. [The values are transformed to floating point a bit differently.](https://github.com/openimaj/openimaj/blob/df945aea4d037dbfae89ebb475966d1062c1cb63/core/core-audio/src/main/java/org/openimaj/audio/samples/SampleBuffer16Bit.java#L154)

```java
samples[2 * sampleIndex] = (float) sampleIntValue * Integer.MAX_VALUE / Short.MAX_VALUE;
```

4. [Real parts are normalized.](https://github.com/openimaj/openimaj/blob/545969f7a99c13bb5bd02c0a30f55013e4abca72/audio/audio-processing/src/main/java/org/openimaj/audio/analysis/FourierTransform.java#L146-L155)

```java
for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i += 2) samples[i] /= fftSize;
```

5. [No logarithms are used for fetching magnitudes.](https://github.com/openimaj/openimaj/blob/545969f7a99c13bb5bd02c0a30f55013e4abca72/audio/audio-processing/src/main/java/org/openimaj/audio/analysis/FourierTransform.java#L223-L245)

```java
final Map<Float, Float> frequenciesToMagnitudes = IntStream.range(0, samples.length / 4)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                index -> (((float) (index * 2)) * (sampleRate / (float) numberOfSamples)) / 2,
                index -> {
                    final float realPart = samples[index * 2];
                    final float imaginaryPart = samples[index * 2 + 1];
                    return (float) Math.sqrt(realPart * realPart + imaginaryPart * imaginaryPart);
                }
        ));
```

After all the changes, the output appears to be much more reasonable:

```
▁▁▂▁▁▁█▁▁▁▂▁▁▁▂▁
```

I am still not entirely sure if the frequency calculation is correct, though.